# VBA Excel Sheet Method doesn't work after Office updates

Tags: vba, excel

I have a script that it takes datas from CSV file and after it generates a graphic. After many Office updates this script has finished to work. It isn't possible come back with Office version.

This is the code:

```
Dim sheet
    For Each sheet In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
        Select Case sheet.Name
            Case "Archive": Sheets(sheet.Name).Delete
            Case "Trend":  Sheets(sheet.Name).Delete
            Case "PivotTable": Sheets(sheet.Name).Delete
        End Select
Next
```

I receive the follow error: "Application defined or object defined error". This error arrives on Select Case, because my object "sheet" hasn't the method "Name".

I have tryed to declare "sheet" as Worksheet

```
Dim sheet as Worksheet
    For Each sheet In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
        Select Case sheet.Name
            Case "Archive": Sheets(sheet.Name).Delete
            Case "Trend":  Sheets(sheet.Name).Delete
            Case "PivotTable": Sheets(sheet.Name).Delete
        End Select
    Next
```

At the first cicle of script I haven't any problem, from the second cicle I have the error: "Type mismatch"

How can I solve it?

Thanks

Comment: Does `ActiveWorkbook.WorkSheets` and `worksheets(sheet.name)' work?

Comment: Did you try running the code in debug mode, setting a breakpoint just after the like `For each...` and examine the value of `sheet`? Which version of Office are you using right now?

Answer (score 1):

**Note**: This is not necessarily the answer, but it is too long to write down as a comment.

You can keep your coding a lot cleaner and simplier: I prefer not to use `sheet` as it's very similer to `Sheet`.
Also, it's better if you avoid using `ActiveWorkbook`.

```
Dim Sht             As Worksheet

For Each Sht In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
    Select Case Sht.Name

        Case "Archive", "Trend", "PivotTable"
            Sht.Delete

    End Select

Next Sht
```

Answer (score 1):

[Sheets](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193217.aspx) can contain [Chart](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194426.aspx) or [Worksheets](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff835542(v=office.15).aspx) objects

then

if you want to delete `Worksheets` only then:

```
Dim sheet As Worksheet
For Each sheet In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets '<-- loop through Worksheets collection
    Select Case sheet.Name
        Case "Archive": Sheets(sheet.Name).Delete
        Case "Trend":  Sheets(sheet.Name).Delete
        Case "PivotTable": Sheets(sheet.Name).Delete
    End Select
Next
```

if you want to delete both `Worksheets` and `Charts` then:

```
Dim sheet As variant '<-- a Variant variable can be assigned both a Worksheet and a Chart object
For Each sheet In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets '<-- loop through Worksheets and Charts collections
    Select Case sheet.Name
        Case "Archive": Sheets(sheet.Name).Delete
        Case "Trend":  Sheets(sheet.Name).Delete
        Case "PivotTable": Sheets(sheet.Name).Delete
    End Select
Next
```